# Sum over numeric string values in SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have numeric values stored in a column of a Spark SQL database as strings. I store these numeric values as strings since they can potentially overflow all numeric datatypes (>128bit numbers).

So far, I could use the normal `SUM()` function to sum up values. **I am curious if it's always safe to do this and how I can deal with cases where it doesn't work.**

My thoughts:
I think internally numeric string values are casted to real numeric datatypes during the summation. In cases where this internal casting fails, the whole summation will fail.

Comment: Whenever you `sum` strings there's an implicit casting involved. Looking at [the spark's docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html) the largest numerical type supports 32 bit numbers. So IMO it's not safe to sum them.

Comment: Just curious, what are you counting, number of atoms in the universe? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decimal type has maximum of 38 digits. It is not mentioned in [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DecimalType.html) actually, but you get an error trying to create a type with bigger precision. [Databricks docs](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/data-types/decimal-type.html) state this explicitly.

Still, 38 digits allow you to store and safely add 126-bit (`log2(10^38)`) numbers.

```scala
val df = Seq(
  "123456789012345678901234567890",
  "1",
  "100000100000100000100000100001"
).toDF("x")

df.withColumn("x", $"x".cast(new DecimalType(38))).agg(sum($"x")).show(false)
+------------------------------+
|sum(x)                        |
+------------------------------+
|223456889012445679001234667892|
+------------------------------+
```

If you need even more you can create a [custom aggregate function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html) operating on strings.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator

object BigSum extends Aggregator[String, String, String] {
  def zero: String = "0"
  def reduce(buffer: String, x: String): String = (BigInt(buffer) + BigInt(x)).toString
  def merge(b1: String, b2: String): String = (BigInt(b1) + BigInt(b2)).toString
  def finish(b: String): String = b
  def bufferEncoder: Encoder[String] = Encoders.STRING
  def outputEncoder: Encoder[String] = Encoders.STRING
}

val big_sum = udaf(BigSum)
df.agg(big_sum($"x")).show(false)
+------------------------------+
|bigsum$(x)                    |
+------------------------------+
|223456889012445679001234667892|
+------------------------------+
```

PS. My BigSum is not super efficient due to converting back and forth, it would be better to have buffer as BigInt - I just didn't know how to write Encoder[BigInt]...